# Old-fashioned indeed?

Tags: contemporary-english

William Safire once wrote that "indeed" sounds old-fashioned, so it's disappearing from contemporary speech. Is Safire right that "indeed" is slowly fading in the horizon of common day usage?

Comment: Have you tried to find any answers? What have you found?

Comment: Contemporary use: "Possibly one of the most convenient words I've come across, it kills off unwanted conversation very effectively without offending someone" (Edited) *Indeed.* http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=indeed

Comment: @Kris While denizens of this site may know about ngrams and corpora, the average questioner does not necessarily know where to begin such a search. It is not like dictionaries or encyclopedia.

Comment: @Kris Can backfire if overdone. Who can forget Laurie's Wooster's "Hold on a minute there, Jeeves. There's an irritating sense, whenever you use 'Indeed Sir', that you really mean 'Says you' "? (Well obviously I can; that's a dreadful paraphrase.)

Comment: @bib Why nGrams & corpora? Have I mentioned them? Furthermore, nGrams are **not** to be used by themselves in drawing inferences. Corpora too can provide supportive data/ leads, but not canonical answers. I suspect the comment was directed at someone else (?)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Note that the cited source is UD, so a generous pinch of, well...

Comment: This question is based on an unfounded premise.

Comment: @Kris Are you claiming that Bertie Wooster is an authority preferable to UD?

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, it would seem so (though bear in mind that ngrams are often best considered with enough pinches of salt as to ruin a low-sodium diet):
[image]

I'd also agree that it does sound old fashioned, though in some contexts more than others; as an interjection it sounds more old-fashioned than as an adverb.

I don't think it's going to reach that horizon though any time soon though. It remains useful enough to linger on.

Comment: Indeed it does.

Comment: One context where it still enjoys high frequency is in academic writing: examples like “… and that is indeed what we find” or “indeed, there is no reason to suppose that …” are legion in articles, at least within the field of linguistics.

Comment: I rather agree with you.

Comment: Sure does, @AndrewLeach

Comment: It is often a word that can be easily cut without loss of meaning, which is something a lot of modern styles encourage.

Comment: It's mainly confined to formal registers. And 'The Ugly Duckling' song.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I submit that the degree to which it might be used in less formal registers varies geographically. I conceded that the degree to which "I submit that" does so, probably does not. Also, the variant "yes indeedy" is mainly confined to the informal.

Answer (score 0):

it does sound a little bit old-fashioned, but that serves to make it more emphatic: "A nose in need, deserves 'Puffs', *indeed*. (From the "Puffs" tissue ad.)

It can be used to impress one's sincerity, where it might otherwise be ambiguous:

"You're an asshole," can be overlooked much more readily than "You are *indeed* an asshole."

Answer (score 0):

To shut down fawning flattery from someone you despise and whose skill level is inferior to your own (it does happen). "This is high praise, indeed." This statement is sarcastic. It implies the flattery is worthless coming from the speaker because they no nothing about the subject matter they are talking about. This line was spoken by John Cleese in a 'Cheers' episode. Diane (Shelly Long) heaps pseudo-intellectual flattery on Cleese's new book.

Comment: Please acknowledge the source.

Comment: This is chiefly British. I heard it said by John Cleese in a 'Cheers' tv episode. Cleese played an author of a famous book title and Shelly's character (in her pseudo-intellectual way) heaps flattery on Cleese who responds with the 'high praise' line.